# PHP creating global mysql insert variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on an examination system. This code inserts all questions answered by students to the table `studentquestions`.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $ice=$_POST['ice'];
    $index = 0;
    foreach($ice as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo $val;// Use $key as an index, or...
        // ... manage the index this way..
        for($i=0; $i<$index; $i++){
            $INSERT=$connection->query("INSERT into student_questions(std_id,test_id,que_id,student_answer)
                                    VALUES
                                    ('1','1','$index','$val')");
        var_dump($INSERT);
        }
        //echo "Index is $index\n";
        $index++;

    }   
        if($INSERT==true){
            session_destroy(test_code);
            session_destroy(t_id);
            session_unset(test_code);
            session_unset(t_id);
            header('Location:sdf.php');
        }else{
            echo "Nothing Added";
        }     
}
```

The problem is that even if the record is added to the database the last `if` statement is not executed. How do I redirect the user if the record is added to the database successfully?

Thank you all i updated the code which is working fine. but when the test have only question it won't insert any record? how to handle this issue

Comment: Before forEach put $INSERT = false;

Comment: The `$i < $index` loop test doesn't seem right.

Comment: that `for` loop seems totally wrong. You're not using `$i` anywhere in the loop, so you're inserting the same thing multiple times.

Comment: You gave $INSERT and u r checking with $insert... PHP is case sensitive.. change it and everything will be fine..

Comment: Hi, you should let your code as it was before, and upvote Tim's answer and accept it so that it is clear to everybody it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP variables are case sensitive - you have $INSERT and $insert which are not the same, try changing your code to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $ice=$_POST['ice'];
    $index = 0;
    foreach($ice as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo $val;
        // Use $key as an index, or...
        // ... manage the index this way..
        for($i=0; $i<$index; $i++){
        $insert = $connection->query
                        ("INSERT into student_questions(std_id,test_id,que_id,student_answer)
                        VALUES
                        ('1','$t_id','$index','$val')");
        //var_dump($insert);
        }
        $index++;
    }        
        if($insert==true){
            session_unregister(t_id);
            session_unregister(test_code);
            session_unset(t_id);
            session_unset(test_code);
            header('Location:sdf.php');
        }else{
            echo "Nothing Added";
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As marco said, initialize your $insert variable to false before. And be careful of the difference between $INSERT and $insert.